# Returning Structure from function Swift 4

Tags: swift, function, struct

I have request function, and after getting JSON. I parse data into instance of structure. How i can return this instance from my function?Now it is returning instance with nil variables.

Getting JSON and parsing it into structure is working correctly, problem with returning instance.

```
class FinantialRequest {

        static func getData(id: Int, year: Int, mod : String, period: String)->CinemaChartModel{

            let parameters: Parameters = [
                "idc": id,
                "yy": year,
                "func": mod
            ]
            var chartModelSample = CinemaChartModel()
            request("https://placeholder.com/app.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).debugLog().responseJSON { responseJSON in
                switch responseJSON.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    do {
                        let parsedData = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(FinDataSample.self, from: value)
                        parsedData.data.forEach { sample in

                            switch sample.b.name {
                                case "Оборот кино":
                                    switch finantialDataSample.period! {
                                        case "1 Квартал":
                                            chartModelSample.moneyPeriodCinema = sample.k1
                                            chartModelSample.moneyBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k1
                                        case "2 Квартал":
                                            chartModelSample.moneyPeriodCinema = sample.k2
                                            chartModelSample.moneyBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k2
                                        case "3 Квартал":
                                            chartModelSample.moneyPeriodCinema = sample.k3
                                            chartModelSample.moneyBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k3
                                        case "4 Квартал":
                                            chartModelSample.moneyPeriodCinema = sample.k4
                                            chartModelSample.moneyBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k4
                                        default: break
                                        }
                                chartModelSample.moneyYyCinema = sample.yy
                                chartModelSample.moneyBudgetYyCinema = sample.b.yy
                            case "Количество людей":
                                switch finantialDataSample.period! {
                                    case "1 Квартал":
                                        chartModelSample.peoplePeriodCinema = sample.k1
                                        chartModelSample.peopleBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k1
                                    case "2 Квартал":
                                        chartModelSample.peoplePeriodCinema = sample.k2
                                        chartModelSample.peopleBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k2
                                    case "3 Квартал":
                                        chartModelSample.peoplePeriodCinema = sample.k3
                                        chartModelSample.peopleBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k3
                                    case "4 Квартал":
                                        chartModelSample.peoplePeriodCinema = sample.k4
                                        chartModelSample.peopleBudgetPeriodCinema = sample.b.k4
                                    default: break
                                    }
                                chartModelSample.peopleYyCinema = sample.yy
                                chartModelSample.peopleBudgetYyCinema = sample.b.yy
                            default:
                                break
                        }
                    }

                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
            return chartModelSample
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the request method is a **Closure** itself, you can't return directly from it. You need to make completion handler like this:

```
static func getData(id: Int, year: Int, mod : String, period: String, completion: ((CinemaChartModel?)->Void)){

 .............

}
```

and trigger it with your struct like this:

```
completion(chartModelSample)
```

OR it can be triggered with nil value incase you have no value to return like:

```
completion(nil)
```

You can call this method like this:

```
getData(id: Int, year: Int, mod : String, period: String, completion:{ (model) -> Void in
    .......
})
```

Comment: how i need to call it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show "How you can call this method"

Comment: From where you are calling completion handler ?